# Compiler not installed when using configuration.nix

Tags: rust, nixos

### Problem

When trying to install a rust development environment utilizing the standard configuration.nix, the build chain is not fully installed or initialized, resulting in a linker error.

### Steps to reproduce

- Install nixos (I used the plasma installer) https://nixos.org/download
- Modify the /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
- Following the instructions here:

  - https://ryantm.github.io/nixpkgs/languages-frameworks/rust/#rust

```
environment.systemPackages = [
  rustc
  cargo
];
```

- *NOTE*: This threw errors when trying to activate the configuration, so I had to modify the configuration as follows:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    rustc
    cargo
  ];
```

- Activate the configuration with: `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`

Now, you can create a project:  `cargo new rusttest`

But when you try to build it: `cargo build`

I get the following error:

```
error: linker `cc` not found
  |
  = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: could not compile `rusttest` due to previous error\
```

### Shell Alternatives

I'm aware that utilizing the nix-shell (`nix-shell -p rustc cargo`) will result in a working environment, and for now, that's my workaround.  However, I would like the standard configuration method to work.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can add `gcc` to your `environment.systemPackages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that you can install compilers globally to `environment.systemPackages`, this is actually not the "standard configuration" for development tools. The [recommended method](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/103642#issuecomment-727527412) is in fact [`nix-shell`](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell) (or [`nix-develop`](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Development_environment_with_nix-shell#nix_develop) for a flake-based environment), which was specifically designed to create cleanly separated development environments.

For example, you can place a file named `shell.nix` in your project folder with this code:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}: pkgs.mkShell {
  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs.buildPackages; [
    cargo
    rustc
  ];
}
```

Then, you can run `nix-shell` with no arguments from your project directory to get a consistent Rust development environment each time, while still granting you the ability to use different tools and configurations for different projects without creating conflicts. Because it runs in user-space and has such reproducible results (including on non-NixOS hosts) it can even be safely checked into source control for others. Reproducibility is what Nix is all about!

This will also install the default C compiler into your shell, which as of this writing is `gcc-12.3.0` for `nixos-23.11`, but you can swap it out as needed for a [different version](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/C#Use_a_different_compiler_version), a [cross-compiler](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/C#Cross-Compiling), [clang](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Using_Clang_instead_of_GCC), etc.

Don't worry about wasting disk space, either: as long as two `nix-shell`s use the exact same version and configuration of the same tool, they will typically share the same package in `/nix/store`. If things change and packages go unused, the [garbage collector](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/garbage-collector.html) will eventually remove them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this with references.  I was not really thinking about using the shell.nix approach, as I'm still trying to figure out where the various "customizations" need to be made.  Nix is very flexible -- almost  to the point where it's confusing.  I appreciate the clarity here.

Comment: no prob. in most cases you probably don't need a whole lot of customization to your dev tools, but having them consolidated in the place where they are actually used, your project folder, is honestly benefit enough. (i don't think i fully explained this benefit, so i made an edit)