Can't replicate `nix-shell` with `nixos-rebuild switch`
I recently installed NixOS and I ran into an issue that I was able to solve with nix-shell, but when I tried to replicate the solution in my configuration.nix, the problem came back.
The issue was related to openssl and pkg-config not being installed, so I solved it by doing the following:
nix-shell -p openssl pkg-config

However, when I added those packages to my configutation.nix. i.e.
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  ...
  openssl
  pkg-config
  ...
];

after doing nixos-rebuild switch the problem persisted.
Why does nix-shell do what I expected but nixos-rebuild switch does not? is there a significant difference between the two? or could there be some configuration process I am missing after rebuild?
I am a complete novice when it comes to NixOS and I don't know much about openssl or pkg-config so any help is appreciated.

might be because of some environment differences used for nix-shelland nixos-rebuild. Try to ask on discourse.nixos.org

possible duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77681190/5904738

@bug thanks. The link you shared there does explain it. I guess the C/C++ compiler infrastructure requires a nix-shell. This clarifies it.

@palik, thanks for that link to the nixos discourse. It will definitely come in handy for me in the future.
